# How to use grep to find the most frequent year in a text file and output that year?

Tags: linux, grep

The text file I am using contains top-selling songs. It is structured as follows:

```
Single,Artist,Record label,Released,Chart,Traditional sales peak,
```

some example lines:

```
Imagine,John Lennon,Apple,Oct-75,1,1714351
Uptown Funk,Mark Ronson featuring Bruno Mars,RCA,Dec-14,1,1647310
Wonderwall,Oasis,Creation,Oct-95,2,1502270
```

I am trying to find which what year has the hits in the file.

I am aware that there are more efficient commands I can use such as `awk`, however I need to complete this using `grep`.

Any help or guidance is appreciated :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go:

```
 $ grep -oP '^([^,]+,){3}\w+-\K\d+' file | sort | uniq -c
  1 14
  1 75
  1 95
```

But as far as we don't have the century, there's some weird results needing a complicated process/heuristic

Comment: What affect does the -P option have? I am new to grep and I tried looking it up but I dont understand what Peral-compatible means.

Comment: It means that you can use Perl regex with that switch.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)